# Empty content script fails with "Failed to execute 'query' on 'Permissions': Illegal invocation"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have been working on this Chrome extension for months and suddenly my content script (i.e. the part running in the web page) started to fail. Trying to produce a minimal example led me to the empty script:

```js
(async () => {
    return true;
})();
```

Here is what I see in the Developer Tools (under Opera) whenever I reload the page:
[image]

The permissions in `manifest.json`:

```json
"permissions": ["identity", "storage", "activeTab"]
```

If I change permissions to:

```json
"permissions": []
```

then it changes to:

[image]

So, there still seems to be an unhandled exception, but I am not being told what it is.

The exception happens both in Opera and in Chrome.

What could have happened and how do I fix this?

**UPDATE** Reloading the extension did not help. Neither did restarting the browser. The issue disappeared after restarting the computer.

Comment: This code can't cause such an error so it's probably a bug in Chrome.